# How safe is SSH when used for tunneling?

Tags: ssh, networking, security, encryption, ssh-tunneling

Scenario: I want to connect from Client A to Client B using SSH/SFTP. I can not open ports on either client. To solve this issue, I got a cheap VPS to use as a relay server.

On Client B I connect to the VPS with remote port forwarding as followed:

```
ssh -4 -N -f -R 18822:localhost:22 <user>@<vps-ip>
```

On the VPS I've set up local port forwarding using `-g` (global) like this:

```
ssh -g -f -N -L 0.0.0.0:18888:localhost:18822 <user>@localhost
```

That way I can connect from Client A directly to Client B at `<vps-ip>:18888`. Works great.

Now my question is, how safe is this? As far as I know, SSH/SFTP connections are fully encrypted, but is there any chance of making it less secure by using the VPS in the middle?

Let's assume these two cases:

Case A: The VPS itself is not altered with, but traffic and files are monitored completely.

Case B: The VPS is completely compromised, filesystem content can be altered.

If I now send a file from Client A to Client B over SFTP, would it be possible for the company hosting the VPS to "intercept" it and read the file's (unencrypted) content?

Comment: The SSH traffic is protected end-to-end (no matter what is in the middle). That is: each end has the correct keys to encrypt and decrypt the content in the connection. Nobody else has those keys, well, as long as the crypto is sound and the **implementation** is correctly done, the probability of that happening is vanishingly small. Understand that the probability is not zero and mistakes on implementation do happen.  However, that is the best we've got yet.

Comment: @Isaac Would you mind leaving a full answer so I can accept it? Some technical references would be nice too!

Comment: @confetti Please, remember to award the bounty to the answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## What you did

You used **three** ssh commands:

1. While inside a **B** console you did:

   ```
   ssh -4 -N -f -R 18822:localhost:22 <user>@<vps>
   ```

   Command sshd (the server) to open port `18822`, a **remote** port `vps:18822` connected to localhost (B) port 22.
2. While at a **vps** console you did:

   ```
   ssh -g -f -N -L 0.0.0.0:18888:localhost:18822 <user>@localhost
   ```

   Command ssh (the client) to open port `18888` available as an **external** (`0.0.0.0`) port on (`vps`) that connects to internal port 18822.

   That opens an internet visible port `vps:18888` that redirects traffic to `18822` which, in turn, redirects to `B:22`.
3. While at a **A** console (and the **only** connection in which A participate):

   Connect from Client **A** directly to Client **B** at `vps:18888`.

What matters is this last connection.
The whole SSH security depends on the **authentication** of **A** to **B**.

## What it means

The [SSH protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell)

> SSH provides a secure channel over an unsecured network

By using [end-to-end encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-to-end_encryption)

> End-to-end encryption (E2EE) is a system of communication where only the communicating users can read the messages. In principle, it prevents potential eavesdroppers – including telecom providers, Internet providers, and even the provider of the communication service – from being able to access the cryptographic keys needed to decrypt the conversation.

End to end encryption is a concept. SSH is a protocol. SSH implements end to end encryption. So can https, or any other number of protocols with encryption.

**If** the protocol is strong,**and** the implementation is correct, the only parties that know the encrypting keys are the two **authenticated** (end) parties.

Not knowing the keys and not being able to break the security of the protocol, any other party is excluded from the contents of the communication.

**If**, as you describe: *from Client A directly to Client B* you are authenticating directly to system B, **then**, only Client A and client B have the keys. No other.

#### Q1

Case A: The VPS itself is not altered with, but traffic and files are monitored completely.

Only the fact that a communication (day, time, end IPs, etc.) is taking place and that some amount of traffic (kbytes, MBytes) could be monitored but not the actual contents of what was communicated.

#### Q2

Case B: The VPS is completely compromised, filesystem content can be altered.

It doesn't matter, even if the communication is re-routed through some other sites/places, the only two parties that know the keys are A and B. That is: **If** the authentication at the start of the communication was between A and B.

Optionally, check the validity of the IP to which A is connecting, then: use public key authentication (use only **once** a private-public key pair that only A and B know), done.

Understand that you **must** ensure that the public key used is carried securely to the system B. You can not trust the same channel to carry the keys and then carry the encryption. There are [Man-in-the-middle attacks that could break the protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-to-end_encryption#Man-in-the-middle_attacks).

#### Q3

> If I now send a file from Client A to Client B over SFTP, would it be possible for the company hosting the VPS to "intercept" it and read the file's (unencrypted) content?

No, if the public keys were safely placed on both ends, there is a vanishingly small probability of that happening.

Walk with the disk with the public key to the other side to install it, never worry again.

---

## Comment

From your comment:

#### Q1

> So, basically the VPS in my setup does nothing but forward the ports, and is not involved in the actual SSH connection or authentication happening from Client A to B, correct?

Kind of. Yes the VPS **should** not be involved in the authentication. But it is "In-The-Middle", that is, it receives packets from one side and delivers them (if it is working correctly) to the other side. But there is an alternative, the VPS (or anything In-The-Middle) could choose to **lie** and [perform a "Man-In-The-Middle-Attack"](https://www.ssh.com/attack/man-in-the-middle). It could lie to Client-A pretending to be Client-B and lie to Client-B pretending to be Client-A. That would reveal everything inside the communication to the "Man-In-The-Middle". That is why I stress the word *should* above.

I [should also say that](https://www.gremwell.com/ssh-mitm-public-key-authentication):

> ...there are no tools implementing MITM against an SSH connection authenticated using public-key method...

Password-based authentication is **not** the public-key method.

If you authenticate with a password, you could be subject to a Man-In-The-Middle-Attack. There are several other alternatives but are out of scope for this post.

Basically, [use ssh-keygen to generate a pair of keys](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/public-key-authentication) (lets assume on side A), and (for correct security) carry the public part inside a disk to Side B and install it in the Authorized-keys file. Do **not** use the network to install the public key, that is: [do not use the ssh-copy-id](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/copy-id) over the network unless you really **do** know exactly what you are doing and you are capable of verifying the side B identity. You need to be an expert to do this securely.

#### Q2

> About the public key though, isn't it, well, public?

- Yes, its public.
  Well, yes, the entity that generated the public-private pair could publish the public part to anyone (everyone) and have lost no secrets. If anybody encrypts with its public key only it could decrypt any message with the matching (and secret) private key.
- SSH encryption.
  By the way, the SSH encryption is symmetric not asymmetric (public). The authentication is asymmetric (either [DH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) ([Diffie-Hellman](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45963/diffie-hellman-key-exchange-in-plain-english)) (for passwords) or [RSA, DSA, Ed25519](https://linux-audit.com/using-ed25519-openssh-keys-instead-of-dsa-rsa-ecdsa/) [Key strength](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/90077/ssh-key-ed25519-vs-rsa) or others (for public keys)), then a symmetric key is generated from that authentication and used as communication encryption key.
- Used for authentication.
  But to SSH, the public key (generated with ssh-keygen) carry an additional secret: It authenticates the owner of the public key.

  If you receive a public key from the internet: How do you know to whom it belongs? Do you trust whatever that public key claims it is? You should not !!

  That is why you should carry the public key file to the remote server (in a secure way) and install it there. After that, you could trust that (already verified) public key as a method to authenticate you to log-in to that server.

#### Q3

> I've connected from the VPS, mostly for testing, to Client B before too, doesn't that exchange the public key already?

It exchange one set of public keys (a set of DH generated public keys) used for encryption. Not the **authentication** public key generated with ssh-keygen. The key used on that communication is erased and forgotten once the communication is closed.

Well, you also accepted (and used) a key to authenticate the IP of the remote server. To ensure that an IP is secure gets even more complex than simple(**??**) public-key authentication.

> My impression was that the public key can be shared, but the private key or passphrase must be kept safe.

And your (general) impression is correct, but the devil is in the details ...

Who generated a key pair could publish his public key without any decrease of his security.

Who receives a public key **must** **independently** confirm that the public key belongs to whom he believes it belongs.

Otherwise, the receiver of a public key could be communicating with an evil partner.

[Generate your key](https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2007/10/05/ssh-keygen-tutorial-generating-rsa-and-dsa-keys/)

Comment: Great answer. So, basically the VPS in my setup does nothing but forward the ports, and is not involved in the actual SSH connection or authentification happening from Client A to B, correct? About the **public** key though, isn't it, well, public? I've connected from the VPS, mostly for testing, to Client B before too, doesn't that exchange the public key already? My impression was that the public key can be shared, but the private key or passphrase must be kept safe.

Comment: @confetti Please read expanded/extended answer.

Comment: Wow, that's an amazing answer. Answered every question I had. Thank you very much. I have the luxury to access both clients physically, so I can and will copy the public key off-line. Especially the ssh.com link was very helpful to understand the concept completely!

Comment: I have not read it all, but I can not see how this is secure: May-be if you run ssh end-to-end over the ssh that stops off at VPS. **But only in this case.** If this is what you intend it is not clear, and will lead to date being exposed to VPS.

Comment: The user stated (and I have reiterate several times) *Client A directly to Client B* How can I be **even more clear** about that? @ctrl-alt-delor

Comment: "ssh -4 -N -f -R 18822:localhost:22 <user>@<vps-ip>” says the opposite to me. I just don't want the OP or any future reader to have their data compromised.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor On the OP description he starts the description of that command (`ssh -4 -N -f -R 18822:localhost:22 <user>@<vps-ip>`) with: **On Client B**, that is, he is making a connection from **B** to the vps. Then he makes an internal port swap (inside the vps) to expose the port to the internet. Then, and this is the critical point: he connects from **A directly to B**. There is no other connection while **On client A**, so, there is no other way in which **A** could connect to anything else. (Cont...)

Comment: (Cont...) In short, there is only **one** authentication of **A** and that is the one that counts. In any case, I have tried to explain and expand the detail of how the connection is being built at the start of this answer to be explicitly clear to you (and other future readers). Is that explained clearly enough for you?   @ctrl-alt-delor

Comment: Point 3 is of utmost importance, and you must insure that you are connected to B

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Of course it is *of utmost importance*, I have already explained this twice in the answer, but to answer your comment: If the user generate a key pair (public-private) in A, carry the public part to B inside a disk and install it there, then, when he authenticate using such key pair there is a vanishingly small chance that he is not connected to the correct B in which disk he installed the public key. If nobody else has that public key, nobody else could use it (or so most experts believe).

Answer (score -1):

If you use ssh to connect A to C, and then C to B, then it is not end to end. It is end to C, and C to other end. C can see what is being transmitted.

For end to end encryption you need ssh to connect the two ends. It matters not what you go through.

If the two ends can not see each other, but can see C, then you can set up (secure or not) connections A—C and B—C. Then use ssh to make a secure connection A—B.

Comment: He is opening a port from **B** to vps, then a redirection from vps to an external port. Then, he claims to be connecting **directly** from **A to B** thru that opened channel. Is it not what he already said?

Comment: Please read: [How to make ssh tunnel open to **public**?](https://superuser.com/q/588591/897702)

Comment: And this [ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples](https://blog.trackets.com/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html)

Comment: May be I am missing something (and so may the OP and future readers), but what I have read is exposing your data. Yes I may be an idiot, compared to you. But if I could read it wrong and make a mistake, then so will others.

Comment: Yes, you are missing that  there is not connection from A to C (and then to B). That is a wrong interpretation. What there is is a three step connection: (1) from B to VPS then (2) an internal port forward from port 18822 to port 18888 inside VPS and then (3) a direct connection of A to B. Please read the expanded description at the start of my answer. As long as the authentication of the last ssh command is **A directly to B** (and keys are not re-used) there could **not** be any data exposition.

Comment: @Isaac Is correct with the "assumptions" (well, I think/hope I made it clear enough in my OP). The SSH (key-based) authentification is done **only** between Client A and B. If I understood everything right you can compare the VPS somehow to an ISP in this scenario. It exists only to forward packages and establish a connection between A and B, but it can not read the contents of the SSH connection, just like your ISP can not if you were to normally connect to an SSH server from your computer.